# Xfinity video not playing

Tags: video, google-chrome, flash, moonlight, pipelight

When I try to watch Xfinity/Comcast videos, the actual video does not load.
I have installed Flash, then installed Pipelight and enabled Silverlight, Flash, Shockwave, and Unity3d.

Other Silverlight and Flash video sources work just fine, including Youtube, Amazon, and Netflix.

I get the commercial, then the player usually loads up (sometimes there's a hang here and I need to reload the page and watch another commercial), but the actual video never shows up.

[image: screencap]

I don't get any error messages.

System info:
Ubuntu 15.10

Chrome info:

```
Google Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
     Revision d177478d466b84ab06f0f48081fc30e3b04be6ca-refs/branch-heads/2623@{#592}
           OS Linux
        Blink 537.36 (@d177478d466b84ab06f0f48081fc30e3b04be6ca)
   JavaScript V8 4.9.385.28
        Flash 21.0.0.182
   User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

Command Line:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --window-depth=24 --window-depth=24 \
    --flag-switches-begin --enable-devtools-experiments \
    --enable-extension-action-redesign --enable-nacl \
    --new-profile-management --enable-print-preview-register-promos \
    --enable-scroll-prediction --enable-spelling-feedback-field-trial \
    --enable-tab-audio-muting --media-router=1 --enable-overlay-scrollbar \
    --enable-features=DownloadResumption,PrintPreviewDistiller \
    --flag-switches-end
```

Firefox just says I have an outdated version of Flash, but it seems as though that's because Flash is no longer being developed for Firefox on Linux.